# Django, login fail and return a raw html code page

Tags: html, django

I wrote a login page, of course it contains a form. Then I wrote my LoginView use class like this:

```
class LoginView(View):
def get(self, request):
    return render(request, "login.html")

def post(self, request):
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if login_form.is_valid():
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'index.html')
            else:
                return render(request, 'login.html', {'msg':'账号未激活！'}, {'login_form':login_form})
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'msg':'用户名不存在！'}, {'login_form':login_form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'msg':'用户名或密码错误！'}, {'login_form':login_form})
```

Ignore the Chinese you may not know.
I tried to input wrong username and password, it should return the same page with error message to allow me to input again, but...
It return a page contains all html code, seems like the browser didn't compile the codes?
If there's a mistake I made in LoginView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the `form.cleaned_data` not `request.POST`,

```
username = login_form.cleaned_data['username']
password = login_form.cleaned_data['password']
```

Comment: problem solved. the {msg} and {login_form} should not be separated